# Do not show the modal message

Tags: html, css, modal-dialog, simplemodal

I'm trying to show a modal message when the user clicks the button using only the css. When I try to add this button to a division, the button does not work anymore. Why?

```css
$colore = #2767ce

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  float: center;
}

.box {
  width: 220px;
  float: center;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  border: 3px solid $colore;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box p {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 40px;
}
  
.scopri {
  display: block;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  background: $colore;
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid $colore;
  outline: 0;
  float: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: .6s ease;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  
  &:hover {
    background: white;
    color: $colore;
    border: 3px solid $colore;
  }
  }
  
.modalita {
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  transition: .3s ease-in-out;
  
  &_box {
    padding: 1em;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    text-align: center;
    transition: all .3s cubic-bezier(.20,.90,.30,1.5);
    transform: rotate(5deg) translate(-1em,1em);
    border-top: 5px solid $colore;
    border-bottom: 5px solid #ddd;
  }
}
  
/* modal magic */
.scopri:focus + .modalita {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
  
  .modalita_box {
    transform: rotate(0deg) translate(0,0);
  }
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <h2>HUB</h2>
  <p>test</p>
<button class="scopri"> more </button>
</div>

<div class="modalita">
  <div class="modalita_box">
    <p> try </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: if you try to remove the division it works but I do not know why!

Comment: what css preprocesser is this?

Comment: less i think or stylus i'm not a very expert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pseudo-classes as in this case, the modalita needs to be a direct or indirect sibling of the element that has the pseudo-class (scopri in this case). That's because CSS child/sibling selectors are fairly restrictive.

You can use it like this:

```
<div class="box">
    <h2>HUB</h2>
    <p>test</p>
<button class="scopri"> more </button>

<div class="modalita">
    <div class="modalita_box">
        <p> try </p>
    </div>
</div>

</div> <!-- closing .box -->
```

Answer (score 1):

The `+` symbol used in `.scopri:focus + .modalita {` is the [Adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), which can only apply to sibling elements.

The `.scopri` button is nested inside the `.box` div, so `.scopri` and `.modalita` are not siblings.

If you move the `.scopri` button outside of the `.box` div, like so:

```
<div class="box">
  <h2>HUB</h2>
  <p>test</p>
</div>
<button class="scopri"> more </button>
```

Then your code should work as intended again.